# Trying to pass an argument/variable into an attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

Imagine I have two models for a Greeting Card App: `Template` and `Card`.  In creating a `Card` you specify the target's `name`, `age`, and which template you want to use (Card `belongs_to template`).  The `Template` just has say `title` and `body:text` attributes.

I would obviously like there to be a placeholder for the target's name (and perhaps age) within the template body, because I want anyone to be able to create a `Card`, select the template, and see a `Card` with the chosen template using their target's name.  Is there a way to pass in an argument to the body of the Template for the target's name?  I have the `Card` and `target` info waiting in the controller but I don't know how to pass it the info since in creating the `Template` the body was typed into a form and is hard coded into the db as an attribute.

The only way around this I see would be to create a view for each `Template` instead of storing them in the database, or to create several 'chunks' of the template body, and insert the target's name in between.  I'd like to figure this out the more efficient way.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to go about this ended up just using a designated keyword in the attribute and then replacing it in the controller using the ruby method .gsub!

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to do this as templates and truly want it store in the db then I would use javascript to replace keys embedded into the text.

This would also offload the search and replace to the client.